# Getting Django ORM data to Javascript for evaluation

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-forms

I have a ORM call that returns values from a database. I pass that to the HTML template, but need that data for a Javascript call. So the process is this:

1. Form loads and calls ORM, gets values from Database (lets call it `db_data`)
2. `db_data` is passed to HTML template `return render(request, "foo.html", db_data)`
3. User in the UI clicks a button in `foo.html`
4. On button click, JS function `set_ui_data()` is called
5. `set_ui_data()` evaluates user selection and presents `db_data` to UI

What is the proper way to give the data from `db_data` to a `set_ui_data()` method for evaluation?

Comment: Convert it to json?

Comment: Thanks @thebjorn - not sure what that means. Convert the ORM call to JSON?

Comment: No, convert/dump the data to a json string (since that is a valid javascript expression), i.e. `import json; json.dumps(db_data)`  assuming `db_data` can be converted to json.

Comment: damn, getting "is not JSON serializable". This looked like an easy way too

Answer (score 0):

You say that you need the data (which you called `db_data`) only after a button click by the user. You could implement that using an asynchronous (ajax) request.

Your views could look something like this:

```
class FooTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'foo.html'

def data_view(request):
    # get data from database here
    db_data = ... something ...

    return JsonResponse(db_data)
```

And in your template, the button would make an ajax call, maybe using `$.get("/your/data/url/")` in the UI buttons `onClick` event (this part depends a lot from your UI setup).

This way, the value returned by your view `data_view` will be available to you as a JS object after the ajax call. Maybe this points you in the right direction.